# Need Help regarding compiling Direct Sound using MinGW or any other C++ compiler if MinGW is not a very viable option

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

My problem is that I am trying to create a DLL of a C++ project which uses Direct Sound source and header files. There is a file called dsound.lib which i need to include. When I compile my code I get following errors

Compiling source file(s)...
RtAudio.cpp
RtAudio.cpp:3477:20: dsound.h: No such file or directory
RtAudio.cpp: In member function `virtual unsigned int RtApiDs::getDeviceCount()':
RtAudio.cpp:3580: error:`LPDSENUMCALLBACK' was not declared in this scope
RtAudio.cpp:3580: error: `DirectSoundEnumerate' was not declared in this scope
RtAudio.cpp:3589: error: expected`)' before "deviceQueryCallback"
RtAudio.cpp:3589: error: `DirectSoundCaptureEnumerate' was not declared in this scope
RtAudio.cpp:3580: warning: unused variable 'DirectSoundEnumerate'
RtAudio.cpp:3589: warning: unused variable 'DirectSoundCaptureEnumerate'
RtAudio.cpp: In member function`virtual RtAudio::DeviceInfo RtApiDs::getDeviceInfo(unsigned int)':
RtAudio.cpp:3626: error: `LPDIRECTSOUND' was not declared in this scope

And there are 153 such errors.
The first line of the error message says that dsound.h not found, but I have that header file in my project. I do not understand what the problem is.

Can some one please suggest any solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of MinGW (i.e. which version of gcc) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of MinGW lack the necessary headers to build against DirectShow.  Try using a MinGW which includes gcc 4.4 or above.

This problem is described in a blog posting from the Qt development team, for which MinGW is a supported compiler.  They had problems building the Windows implementation of their multimedia module (Phonon) using MinGW, as described in [this posting](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/07/15/phonon-and-mingw-a-story-about-true-windows-love/).